# Ember error:Ember is not defined no-undef

Tags: ember.js

Hi I am following through with Plural sight course "Getting started with Ember 2"; I am stuck with this error: 'Ember' is not defined  no-undef;
my code looks like this ember dot dollar sign dot get json two brackets; this is inside route ; the code works fine with static data. I am sorry the editor would not allow me to paste my code

Comment: You can use <pre> </pre> for wrapping the code. or tilde char wrap for code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update:

Right way and best practice is to import `Ember` like this `import Ember from "ember";`

---

This is just lint error. you can add an exception for `Ember`. In .eslintrc.js file you can add

```
"globals": { "Ember": true }
```

Or if you dont want this rule be enabled then you can turn it off

```
rules: {
"no-unused-vars": "off"
}
```

Comment: Don't turn off the rule and import ember instead of relying on the global.